Variable and Memory Allocation?
Do both of these programs consume the same memory and time?
def conv(txt):
   a=int(txt)     #Does the variable "a" consumes extra memory?
   return a
print(conv("4"))

def conv(txt):
   return int(txt)
print(conv("4"))

I am a beginner in python, so I couldn't understand how the memory allocation works when implementing method on a piece of data in python.

If you'd like some insight into how the methods are implemented internally, you could add import dis to the top of your file, and dis.dis(conv) to the bottom, and that will print out the opcodes that the CPython runtime converted the method into.

Not sure what you mean by "Methods" in your question.

No they do not. The first version requires more code and memory (for the variable a). The second version is more efficient in both respects

In the first program, a variable called "a" is created to store the integer conversion while in the second program, the integer conversion is directly returned without creating an extra variable. Creating the extra variable in the first program takes up a tiny bit more memory.
In terms of time, both programs are likely to be very similar in speed because the difference in how they handle the conversion is quite small. So, for practical purposes, you can consider them to be almost the same in terms of memory and time usage.
